# How to import JSON in Javascript/React properly? (VS Code)

Tags: javascript, json, ecmascript-6, import

I have this example file (example.json):

`{"test": {"name": "testName"}}`

Then, in my js file I import like this:

`import testJson from "./example.json"`

When I type: 
`testJson.`

I want suggestions to appear in the IDE (preferably in VS Code).

How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 2):

Use [Node JSON Autocomplete](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=bhshawon.node-json-autocomplete) it will add autocomplete in vscode.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your response. Does nothing for me unfortunately. Do I need so set anything up apart from installing?

Comment: VS Code version is 1.44.0

Answer (score 1):

You don't need any extensions for this.

JSON imports are not supported in every module system so you need to tell VS Code that such imports are valid. To do this, in your [jsconfig](https://code.visualstudio.com/Docs/languages/javascript#_javascript-projects-jsconfigjson) file, just add:

```
"resolveJsonModule": true
```

This will not only let you auto complete json import paths, but also give you proper intellisense for the import.

[image: IntelliSense for a package.json]

VS Code 1.44+ also automatically enables `resolveJsonModule` in  all JS files that do not belong to a `jsconfig`:

[image: Default behavior in VS Code 1.44]

Again though, if you have a jsconfig or tsconfig you'll need to explicitly set `"resolveJsonModule": true`